# How could I Prevent Hard Coded Intial State of Reducer in Redux whilst initial rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

**I get category state items via the reducer's initial state but it looks a bit of a messy and hard-coded way to get of redux state, for that reason, I just want to fetch the dummy JSON data that I created by myself and serve with json-server package, but, I could not set the initial state witch dispatching redux-saga before the render inside of the useEffect hooks. Is there a way to solve this situation ?**

You can understand the story of the action below the code blocks;

*Reducer Blok; without the initial dispatch that I want to change with an empty object the code block below*

```
export const getCategoryReducer = (
    state = {
        category: [
            {
                id: '1',
                name: 'bread',
                url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/210/00FF00?text=1',
                alt: 'bread',
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                name: 'croissant',
                url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/220/00FF00?text=2',
                alt: 'sdfalksdjflkasjdfk',
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                name: 'birthday-cake',
                url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/230/00FF00?text=3',
                alt: 'sdfalksdjflkasjdfk',
            },
        ],
        loading: false,
        err: '',
    },
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_CATEGORY:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        case GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                category: action.category,
                loading: false,
            };
        case GET_CATEGORY_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                err: action.message,
                loading: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Note: initialState has more items than this above code block

*I tried the UseEffect Hooks with dispatch action via Redux-saga but it won't load json-server bakery category items before the page render;*

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCategoryFetch('Bakery'));
    }, []);
```

**This is the generator function that triggers when action pass then fetch the data from local sever that I created by json-server;**

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const categoryFetch = async (category) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3500/categories:`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    }

    const data = await res.json();

    return data[`${category}`];
};

function* getCategory(action) {
    try {
        const category = yield call(categoryFetch, action.payload);
        yield put({ type: GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, category });
    } catch (err) {
        yield put({ type: GET_CATEGORY_FAIL, message: err.message });
    }
}

export default function* mySagaCategory() {
    yield takeLatest(LOAD_CATEGORY, getCategory);
}
```

State render dynamic category items in the code below;

````
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import Skeleton, { SkeletonTheme } from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import {
    LazyLoadImage,
    LazyLoadComponent,
} from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import './ProductContainer.css';

const ProductConatiner = ({ category, err, loading, clickHandler }) => {
    if (loading) {
        document.querySelector('.progress-item').style.display = 'none';
        return (
            <SkeletonTheme className="container">
                <Skeleton
                    color="grey"
                    highlightColor="#AAA"
                    className="handle skeleton"
                    // duration={2.5}
                    // height="55"
                ></Skeleton>
            </SkeletonTheme>
        );
    }

    if (err.length > 0) {
        document.querySelector('.progress-item').style.display = 'none';
        return (
            <h1
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    color: 'red',
                }}
            >
                {err + ' reload the page'}
            </h1>
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector('.progress-item').style.display = 'block';
    }, []);

    function quantityHandler() {
        console.log('quantityHandler');
    }

    const Images = useMemo(() => {
        return category.map((el, idx) => {
            return (
                <LazyLoadComponent>
                    <LazyLoadImage
                        delayTime={250}
                        delayMethod="throttle"
                        useIntersectionObserver={true}
                        threshold={500}
                        effect="opacity"
                        key={el.id}
                        src={el.url}
                        alt={el.name}
                    />
                    <input
                        key={idx + 'input'}
                        className="image-input"
                        onChange={quantityHandler}
                        type="number"
                        value="1"
                    ></input>
                    <label>kg</label>
                </LazyLoadComponent>
            );
        });
    }, [category]);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button
                onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e.target)}
                className="handle left-handle"
            >
                <div className="text">&#8249;</div>
            </button>
            <div className="slider">{Images}</div>
            {/* <div className="inputs">{quantityItems} </div> */}
            <button
                onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e.target)}
                className="handle right-handle"
            >
                <div className="text">&#8250;</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductConatiner;
```
````

Comment: Why not fetch the JSON data first, ***then*** instantiate the redux store, i.e. pass the initial state to the store when it's created? Or continue with the dispatch to fetch the JSON data when the component/app initially renders and use appropriate guard clauses/checks prior to accessing into any potentially undefined state.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant in your comment.

Comment: In fact, that work's correct if I were just put the initial state, but I don't want to do it, in this way. So, I try to dispatch an action , however , it won't load the fetch data and  store state before page render .

Comment: That's why I suggested to fetch the data prior to creating the store and loading the app, or fetch the data in the `useEffect` when the component mounts and guard any undefined accesses until the data is available. Does this JSON data ***need*** to be fetched? Why can't you just declare it in a file and import it?

Comment: I fetched that into useEffect when component mounts but it won't work , the problem comes from dynamic elements creation that İ added a new code block. You would understand  what I mean.

Comment: If hardcoding the initial state works in the reducer function then saving that same data in a file and importing it for use as the initial state should work just the same. If this data is "dynamic" and can't just be a file then fetching it when the app mounts is likely the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly normal that this doesn't load before page render, and even if you would find a way to do this (by delaying the start of your application), it doesn't reflect the "reality" of today's React development.

It is normal that your component renders without the data it needs, THEN a useEffect is executed, and any time later (could be 10ms, could be 10s) the server answers. In-between your component is responsible for detecting that the data is not there and rendering a "loading" state.
As this pattern will be reality for almost everything you do, you will not learn something substantial by "cheating around" it in this case. Learn it right from the start.

All that said, the style of Redux you are using here is severely outdated. Modern Redux (since 2019) does not use switch..case reducers or ACTION_TYPES. Also, Redux-saga is not recommended anymore for most use cases. Since modern Redux is only about 1/4 of the code, you are not only writing outdated code, you are also writing unnecessary amounts of code. Please give [this article about modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) a read and then consider following [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

PS: what you are doing there with `document.querySelector`, using css styles of an external element as "state source" is problematic - updating those external values will never make your component rerender. That means your component and those external values will easily run out of sync. Use local or global (Redux) state for this, but not arbitrary element properties. Those are not synced with your application lifecycle.

Comment: I see what you mean, I would check and refactor the code base to be a concise and more powerful way. Thank you for your suggestion, I appreciated it.

Comment: You wrote in PS that I use a slider that I made by myself, beside I create the progress bar according to the amount of the img element that resides inside of the slider container. In the state of error or loading it has to be display:none otherwise it has to be shown. Not a compose a huge problem that you were mention actually it works correctly .

Comment: But you are using React! Why not make that a React component that reacts to state changes? You are completely ignoring the tool at your hands!

Comment: In fact, those `document.querySelector` functions implement on category, err, and loading states change React to state changes behind the scenes. I don't want to re-render the again on style changes again. It does not depend on any state.

Comment: @aarnautovic It's a React anti-pattern to query the DOM directly, use a React ref where you can, or do it in a more React-y way via the `className` or `style` props. It's also a React anti-pattern to mutate the DOM, even more so as an unintentional side-effect, if you ***must*** do this then at least do it as an intentional side-effect in a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese I'll refactor it glad for your advice.